# log file handling with docker syslog logging driver

Tags: docker, syslog, rsyslog

Is there a way to pick up the log messages which are logged to a log file, when using the syslog log driver of Docker?

Whatever I write to sysout are getting picked by Rsyslog but anything logged to a log file is not picked. I don't see any option in the syslog driver option which could help indicate a log file to be picked up.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[Dockers logging interface](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/) is defined as stdout and stderr, so the best way is to modify the log settings of your process to send any log data to [stdout and stderr](https://github.com/docker-library/httpd/blob/b13054c7de5c74bbaa6d595dbe38969e6d4f860c/2.2/Dockerfile#L72-L75).

Some applications can configure logging to go directly to syslog. Java processes using [log4j](https://www.badllama.com/content/tomcat-7-logging-syslog-log4j) are a good example of this.

If logging to file is the only option available, [scripts](https://logrhythm.com/blog/using-logger-to-send-file-data-to-syslogd/), [logstash](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash-versioned-plugins/current/v4.0.3-plugins-inputs-file.html), [fluentd](https://docs.fluentd.org/v0.12/articles/in_tail), [rsyslog](https://www.rsyslog.com/doc/v8-stable/configuration/modules/imfile.html), and [syslog-ng](https://syslog-ng.com/documents/html/syslog-ng-ose-3.14-guides/en/syslog-ng-ose-guide-admin/html/configuring-sources-file.html) can all ingest text files and output syslog. This can either be done inside the a container with an additional service, or using a shared, standardised logging area on each Docker host and running the ingestion from there.

Comment: Its a mesosphere environment. I don't have any way to do any setup/config on host itself. However, I can configure the container as I create the docker file. Is it possible to do rsyslog configurations within the container? Even I do it, will docker syslog driver use it? I have configured the docker syslog logging driver in marathon json file.

Comment: Does mesosphere provide something like the DaemonSet feature from Kubernetes? It could possibly be setup like that, so every node has a log shipping service running.

Comment: To run in the app container you would need a service manager like [s6](https://github.com/just-containers/s6-overlay) to run both your app and the log shipping at once. rsyslog would send the logs directly to the syslog server, not via docker.

Comment: I an not sure about DaemonSet support in mesosphere and also don't think I have s6. I had tried linux service/systemctl in the container , but don't have permissions for that. we do have a yum repo and I see logging stuff in there, like logrotate, log_noarch etc.
Also, just tried this RUN ls -ltr /etc/rsyslog.d/ and it does not exist.

Comment: You would add s6 in the Dockerfile for the image you are running. Then configure it to run both your app and whatever log forwarding method you choose.